# Is there a way to set up a permanent configuration for ruby-debug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-debug

I see in the ruby-debug docs configuration settings for ruby-debug here:

http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/ruby-debug.html#Debugger_002esettings

But there isn't any mention of creating a configuration file and having these settings set for new ruby-debug sessions.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `. rdebugrc` file in your home directory - it is read each time rdebug starts. You can put any config options in it like this:

```
set autolist
set listsize 25
```